# Obtaining selected item in dynamic radio button

Tags: regex, selenium, xpath, jmeter

I have got radio button like this:

```
<span><input onClick="if (EventHandlers.valueChanged(event, this)==false) return false;"   class="radio"
       label="Temp label" type="radio" 
       id="TempId_01" onblur="EventHandlers.onBlur(event)" 
       name="TempId" 
       value="01" delayOnChange="true" checked></input></span>
```

i want to get a value of checked item. I have tried smth like this (by xpath):

```
//input[@checked and @name="TempId"]/@value
```

However this not work at all, is it valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath queries need to return physical DOM elements that Selenium can work with. Selenium is then responsible for grabbing any attributes, details or properties from that element - your query is, by this point, all over and done with.

So, you'll need something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@checked and @name="TempId"]")).getAttribute("value");
```